# What's the best neural network type for guessing the next number of a sequence?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I want to create a simple neural network that can guess the next number based on a set of numbers given, so something like

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
```

will give an output of

```
9
```

(after training it with test data, of course)
As there are a ton of AI algorithms, what is the most efficient, algorithm in order to accomplish something like this?

Comment: There is no best way. Without a-priori info about this task you can't learn anything, even in theory. Imagine i give you random numbers of 0's and 1's, where you need to predict the next one: the theoretical optimum is as good as random-guessing. Now additionally, with incorporated a-priori knowledge, NNs are still not that suited for this kind of task (in general)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `Genetic Algorithm`. It is very fun and there is bunch of tutorials out there that can help you.

Advantage of this is that your program will not get old if you give him some complex arrays, but he will self learn and improve.